# Facebook Like button pointing to the like.php script, rather than the page itself

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.diacarbon.com%2Fblog%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=220&amp;action=like&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:220px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Currently the page is at http://www.diacarbon.com/blog/

The "LIKE" button on the sidebar, for some reason, is pointing towards the facebook.com/plugins/like.php rather than the www.diacarbon.com/blog URL itself.

Everytime I "LIKE" it, on my Facebook I get an ugly "Jeff likes facebook.com/plugins/like.php...." type of messy URL on there.

Comment: Even the Facebook URL linter shows issues: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.diacarbon.com%2Fblog%2F

Comment: @jefkee: nope, it's working fine...most likely it was a caching problem.

Comment: The like button does load & work - it's just it misses the actual target url.. like this: http://twitpic.com/49naju    even when I do it from the Facebook LIKE button generator page, not on my own site...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Use the XFBML version **WITHOUT** the `href` attribute
2. Add the missing [Open Graph meta tag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) `og:title`
3. Run the site again over the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/)

Comment: I would try the step 2 & 3 first, but I always prefer the XFBML version.

Comment: Already did that earlier - switched to XFBML... I'll try #2 and #3 for sure.

Comment: Nope same thing. We'll know it's working when the like count no longer shows "1" but rather 14 or something of the sort.. 0 might even be better!

Comment: @jefkee: That's really odd! if this is a live website, download it locally, and try (for example) changing the theme and adding the Meta Tags and try again...It may be something wrong with the theme or the social plugins next to each post.